# How to add GPIO to U-Boot SDK source?

Tags: sdk, cross-compiling, bootloader, u-boot

I am tying to build u-boot but get this error:

```
LDS     u-boot.lds
LD      u-boot
common/built-in.o: In function `do_gpio':
/media/saleh/NEWVOLUME/SDK/n-amlogic/uboot/build/../common/cmd_gpio.c:186: undefined reference to `gpio_request'
/media/saleh/NEWVOLUME/SDK/n-amlogic/uboot/build/../common/cmd_gpio.c:194: undefined reference to `gpio_direction_input'
/media/saleh/NEWVOLUME/SDK/n-amlogic/uboot/build/../common/cmd_gpio.c:195: undefined reference to `gpio_get_value'
/media/saleh/NEWVOLUME/SDK/n-amlogic/uboot/build/../common/cmd_gpio.c:200: undefined reference to `gpio_get_value'
/media/saleh/NEWVOLUME/SDK/n-amlogic/uboot/build/../common/cmd_gpio.c:203: undefined reference to `gpio_direction_output'
/media/saleh/NEWVOLUME/SDK/n-amlogic/uboot/build/../common/cmd_gpio.c:209: undefined reference to `gpio_free'
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make[1]: *** [u-boot] Error 139
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

I searched the issue and [the guide](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Embedded-Development-Tools/U-boot-build-failed-reporting-quot-undefined-reference-to-gpio/td-p/659383) was as :

> GPIO is part of minimum configuration of your soc system, trying to
>   add it in your system and rebuild.

But HOW I can add GPIO to the SDK? I am using arm64 architecture with p212 reference board. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is all it takes me to compile U-Boot for the P212 board:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
git clone http://git.denx.de/u-boot.git
cd u-boot
git checkout v2018.05
export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
make mrproper
make p212_defconfig
make
```

For verified boot you need a FIT image. Enable CONFIG_FIT using

```
make menuconfig
```

Comment: can you tell us how you set up your environment? when I follow your guide I encounter consecutive errors about gcc version , ... ! thanks

Comment: U-Boot requires at least gcc 6. On Debian Buster gcc 7 is available. If this does not answer your question, please, provide the output with the errors.

Comment: GCC version is the least of problems and solved but when I enable some configs (specially for verified boot feature) I encounter the error which I wrote here:http://forum.khadas.com/t/verified-u-boot-secure-boot-on-khadas-vim/2559   Did you have tried **verified boot** for p212 board? If yes what repo of uboot you used? Thanks